# Blitting a frame buffer object to the screen

Tags: c++, opengl, fbo

so I am trying to create a frame buffer object in OpenGL using C++ and GLFW/GLEW. I have successfully used VAO's and VBO's to simply render an array of vertices using OpenGL's glDrawArrays method to make a quad on the screen. I then created a multisampled frame buffer object and created its corresponding color buffer and depth buffers, then bound it, then rendered the quad, then unbound the frame buffer object, and then attempted to blit the FBO to the screen. It did not work out so well or at all. Also, if it causes confusion, I made a preprocessor definition called "INRELEASE" if the project is ran in release mode in visual studio so that no console pops up when the program starts.
Here's my code.

Fbo.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "Window.h"

class Fbo
{
public:
    static const int NONE = 0;
    static const int DEPTH_TEXTURE = 1;
    static const int DEPTH_RENDER_BUFFER = 2;

private:
    Window *window;

    const int width;
    const int height;

    GLuint frameBuffer;

    bool multisample;

    GLuint colorTexture;
    GLuint depthTexture;

    GLuint depthBuffer;
    GLuint colorBuffer;

    void initializeFrameBuffer(int type);
    void createFrameBuffer();
    void createTextureAttachment();
    void createDepthTextureAttachment();
    void createMultisampledColorAttachment();
    void createDepthBufferAttachment();

public:
    Fbo(Window *window, int width, int height, int depthBufferType);
    Fbo(Window *window, int width, int height);

    void cleanUp() const;
    void bindFrameBuffer() const;
    void unbindFrameBuffer() const;
    void bindToRead() const;
    void resolveToFbo(Fbo *outputFbo) const;
    void resolveToScreen() const;

    inline int getColorTexture() const { return colorTexture; }
    inline int getDepthTexture() const { return depthTexture; }
};
```

Fbo.cpp:

```
#include "Fbo.h"

#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include <GL\glew.h>

#include <iostream>

Fbo::Fbo(Window *window, int width, int height, int depthBufferType) : width(width), height(height)
{
    this->window = window;

    multisample = false;
    initializeFrameBuffer(depthBufferType);
}

Fbo::Fbo(Window *window, int width, int height) : width(width), height(height)
{
    this->window = window;

    multisample = true;
    initializeFrameBuffer(DEPTH_RENDER_BUFFER);
}

void Fbo::cleanUp() const
{
    glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &colorTexture);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &depthTexture);
    glDeleteRenderbuffers(1, &depthBuffer);
    glDeleteRenderbuffers(1, &colorBuffer);
}

void Fbo::bindFrameBuffer() const
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

void Fbo::unbindFrameBuffer() const
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glViewport(0, 0, window->getWidth(), window->getHeight());
}

void Fbo::bindToRead() const
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
}

void Fbo::resolveToFbo(Fbo *outputFbo) const
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, outputFbo->frameBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
    glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, outputFbo->width, outputFbo->height, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
    unbindFrameBuffer();
}

void Fbo::resolveToScreen() const
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK);
    glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, window->getWidth(), window->getHeight(), GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
    unbindFrameBuffer();
}

void Fbo::initializeFrameBuffer(int type)
{
    createFrameBuffer();

    if (multisample)
        createMultisampledColorAttachment();
    else
        createTextureAttachment();

    if (type == DEPTH_RENDER_BUFFER)
    {
        createDepthBufferAttachment();
    }
    else if (type == DEPTH_TEXTURE)
    {
        createDepthTextureAttachment();
    }

    unbindFrameBuffer();
}

void Fbo::createFrameBuffer()
{
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
}

void Fbo::createTextureAttachment()
{
    glGenTextures(1, &colorTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorTexture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorTexture, 0);
}

void Fbo::createDepthTextureAttachment()
{
    glGenTextures(1, &depthTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, width, height, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture, 0);
}

void Fbo::createMultisampledColorAttachment()
{
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorBuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 4, GL_RGBA8, width, height);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorBuffer);
}

void Fbo::createDepthBufferAttachment()
{
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);

    if (!multisample)
        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, width, height);
    else
        glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 4, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, width, height);

    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>

#include "Window.h"
#include "Fbo.h"
#include "Loader.h"
#include "Renderer.h"

#ifdef INRELEASE
int WinMain()
#else
int main()
#endif
{
    Window window("3D Engine", 800, 600, true);
    Loader loader;
    Renderer renderer;

    float vertices[] = 
    {
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f
    };

    RawModel model = loader.loadToVao(vertices, sizeof(vertices));
    Fbo fbo(&window, window.getWidth(), window.getHeight());

    while (!window.isClosed())
    {
        window.clear();

        fbo.bindFrameBuffer();
        renderer.render(model);
        fbo.unbindFrameBuffer();
        fbo.resolveToScreen();

        window.update();
    }

    fbo.cleanUp();
    loader.cleanUp();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "It did not work out so well" isn't a question.  Please explain what happened.

Comment: I recommend searching gDebugger or glDevil to run the debug version and pause after each gl command to see what is happening to the buffers.

Comment: Robinson, the quad renders fine when I do not bind the FBO, but when I try and render to the FBO and blit it to the screen, the screen is just black

Comment: `glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE` returns true so that cannot be the issue

Comment: @Rabbid76 upon creation of my Window class, I enabled these: `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` and `glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);` and `glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE_ARB);`

Comment: @Robinson forgot to tag you above

Comment: @StarShine how do I use these?

Comment: Just start a new project in glDebugger, point it to your debug executable and hit run. If you break you can see the buffers and variables. You can step through the application per opengl call, per draw command, and per frame.

Comment: @StarShine what should I be looking for while using gDEBugger?

Comment: Check the multi-textured output of your FBO, the textures should be listed also in the list. See if they are updated after each glDrawArrays call. If that's the case, you can move on and inspect the FRONT and BACK buffers. Play with the clear color in your application to see if you are getting any output at all. Worst case, you can simply put a new quad on  the default FBO (0 = default output FBO) and texture it using the output of your previous stage. I've remember using blitting for deferred rendering once, but it is tricky to use in certain cases.

Comment: @StarShine Ok so using gDEBugger, here is setting up the VAO, VBO, and FBO: https://imgur.com/a/PMQus and here is rendering it: https://imgur.com/a/bsQJf